# Ubuntu 12.10+ optimus nvidia 635m and CUDA installation?

Tags: 12.10, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, cuda

I am trying to install CUDA on my ubuntu 12.10 as my computer has Optimus Graphic card 635m. I was able to use the card by bumblebee till I tried to install CUDA. After that I cannot run optirun. I tried to install CUDA by the installation file from nvidia site also use the software manager as the second try. All my shots are failed. Currently I am crazy about the mixure of the card, bumblebee and cuda at 12.10. Is there any one solved that kind of problem at his configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to read this post here: [Nvidia Bumblebee + CUDA](http://ammar.gr/?p=679)
Use the script you find in here. Is the most advanced step further I made untill now, to get the Nvidia card work. After having configured Bumblebee, during the CUDA installation take care not to install again the Nvidia driver as asked by the CUDA installer: if you say 'yes' this will break your Desktop resolution.